# Reason(s) behind restrictions on sex

Tags: scripture, women, sex

There are plenty of restrictions for a grihastha woman to participate in sex.

Some restrictions include **forbidding the sex of Ekadasi, Amavasya,  Poornima, Sunday**.

Is the ban on some special days, independent of women, is for health purposes? Or is there any other reason behind such restriction?

Note that I am not asking for restrictions that are based on women such as restrictions based on her menstrual cycle.

Comment: Those are holy days where sensual pleasures like eating are forbidden.

Comment: leaving aside specific reasons for sex restrictions, there is one generic reason for any restriction - Shakti/Power. if you notice, in life, anybody who has reached any height of success did so by sacrificing something. the more the sacrifice, the higher the height. the tighter a spring is wound, the higher it jumps upon releasing.